# Maven archetype for three frameworks in one project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, struts

We  know  that there is a archetype  of hibernate ,  archetype  of spring ,  archetype  of struts.  how i  can  generae a  structure  of  project  that collect the three  archetype ?
or in other wise, how  to generate a structure of jee project  that collect a set of frameworks ?
thx

Comment: Archetypes are just templates for projects. You can create your own archetype.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the dependencies to a clean maven pom.xml.

```
<project 
...
  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
  </plugin>
</plugins>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring hibernate etc here -->
  <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I would add them one at a time and carefully build up the required configuration for each pieces while making sure the project continues to compile at each step.